# how can I find out my server's subnet mask via SSH

Tags: ssh, ip

Hi I use media tamples dv server... I connected it via SSH with putty.. I need my server's IP address and subnetmask. I know the IP address but I don't know the subnetmask.

How can I find out my server full IP details with ssh?

Comment: I thought Media Tample had 24/7 support is that not included in the price?

Comment: no they don't support dv server. things you do with plesk or ssh you are along..

Comment: Just be aware that network admins can and do play games with a net number having different netmasks at different points on the net. I would expect to see this especially in a hosting environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ssh user@server /sbin/ifconfig -a
```

Comment: hi thanks. it says no such file or directory

Comment: No such file or directory locally? You do not have ssh? or when you login to the server?

Comment: @ErdemEce: Do you find it by `locate ifconfig` or using `find` etc?

Answer (score 3):

This outputs e.g. `/24`:

```
ip addr | 
  awk -v ipaddr=192.168.1.2 '\
    $1 == "inet" && $2 ~ "^" ipaddr "/" \
    {mask=$2; sub("^[^/]*","",mask); print mask}'
```

Make that your SSH command.